# How can I sync my development between my PC and laptop?

Tags: windows, http, deployment, webserver, versioning

I'm trying to create ann architecture that allows me to work on my projects on both devices. I want to somehow sync my hosts file and vhosts between two devices. I could use something like dropbox and host the web server from there, but that still leaves the hosts file not being synced between the two.

I can only imagine there is a much simpler way to do this, except for hosting it in 1 central location. I currently just make lots of vhosts, and add a dummy domain for the website in my hosts file and try my best to keep the two devices in sync as much as I can, but its really tedious.

Is there a better way to do this? I've heard of dockr but I dont think it syncs between devices.

Answer (score 2):

[github](https://github.com)

> GitHub is a development platform inspired by the way you work. From
>   open source to business, you can host and review code, manage
>   projects, and build software alongside 31 million developers.

Alternativly use Gitlab, Bitbucket or any other versioning tool.

Actually, you can also use those tools for deployment. So not only your laptop and desktop get the code from there, but also your server.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Git is to manage a project, or a set of files, as they change over time. Git stores this information in a data structure called a repository.

Github will host your repository for you, without any cost.

[Git wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)

[GitHub website](https://github.com/)

Comment: well private repositories cost money, unless you are student - than you get 2 years for free.